# Java service or APIs to send e-mail using webmin's Sendmail Mail Server

Tags: java, sendmail, restlet, webmin

I want to create a restlet service in Java that sends e-mail to the user, I know how to send e-mail using amazonaws service, amazon provides aws-java-sdk.jar to configure all the settings. But now I want to send e-mail using webmin's Sendmail Mail Server.

So my question is: Is there any jar provided by webmin to configure and send e-mail? if NO then, 
How can I configure the webmin's Sendmail Mail Server to send e-mail using Java restlet service?

Any help is welcome, it would be great if someone provide any link OR tutorial for this.